# Navigating back to main page after logging in

Tags: c#, blazor

I am building a server-side app with Blazor. I am not using any javascript, react and other frameworks. I am using Blazor default template. When I go to the login page and type the right credentials I want to navigate to the Home Page. I am using the following code to do that:

```
  public void LoginCommand()
            {
                var authenticationStatProvider = new TaskClientAuthenticationStateProvider();

                if (this.Username == "Lyubo" && this.Password == "123")
                {
                    TaskClientAuthenticationStateProvider.IsAuthenticated = true;

                    authenticationStatProvider.NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged();

                    NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/home/{this.Username}");
                }
            }
```

I have separated the view from the logic in two files if that matters and my LoginPageBase inherits ComponentBase. After the code above is executed I see this [navigate back to home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z22u1.jpg).

```
@page "/home"
@page "/home/{userName}"
@inherits LayoutComponentBase


<div class="sidebar ">
    <NavMenu />
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="loginpage">
            <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Login
        </NavLink>
    </div>

    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>

@code{
    [CascadingParameter]
    public Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string userName { get; set; }
}
```

It seems that I am somehow duplicating(because I am not navigating just to the @Body, but the entire home page) the main page and I can't figure out how to correct this behavior? How can I place my view in the @Body from another page? Thanks :)

Comment: The issue is probably in your pages composition but not in this `LogiCommand` code. What if you manually navigate to `/home/Lyubo" ?

Comment: Can you give me an example how to do that?

Comment: The result is the same

Comment: So the issue is not in this code.

Comment: This is my home page code https://pastebin.com/ZkAV1CMj .  I think the problem is that I am trying to redirect to the entire page and not just the Body. But I can't figure out how to navigate just to the Body.

Comment: Update your question with the code, It's much more readable.